# Can I pass arguments to a base constructor from a derived class's default constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, abstract-class, derived-class

Suppose I have an abstract base class Deck:

```
public abstract class Deck
{
   public List<Card> cards;

   public Deck(string[] values, string[] suits)
   {...}

   ...
}
```

and a derived class EuchreDeck:

```
public class EuchreDeck : Deck
{
   string[] values = new string[] { "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
   string[] suits = new string[] { "clubs", "spades", "hearts", "diamonds" };

   public EuchreDeck() : base(values, suits) // Error.
   {}

   ...
}
```

I want the ability to instantiate `EuchreDeck` and have the two string arrays passed to the base class, i.e. `var gameDeck = new EuchreDeck();`.

Currently I'm getting the error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property `EuchreDeck.values`."

Is this possible, or will calling the derived default constructor always call the base default constructor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do this if you make the arrays `static`:

```
public class EuchreDeck : Deck
{
   private static readonly string[] values = new string[] { "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
   private static readonly string[] suits = new string[] { "clubs", "spades", "hearts", "diamonds" };

   public EuchreDeck() : base(values, suits)
   {

   }
}
```

The reason why you can't use it as you had with instance-level members is because it's not legal to do so. This comes from the [C# specification 10.10.1 Constructor Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645603%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) where it states:

> An instance constructor initializer cannot access the instance being
>   created. Therefore it is a compile-time error to reference this in an
>   argument expression of the constructor initializer, as is it a
>   compile-time error for an argument expression to reference any
>   instance member through a simple-name.

By switching the arrays to be `static`, they are no longer accessed via the instance but rather by the `EuchreDeck` *type*.

---

That said, I might suggest you take a slight tweak on the design. Maybe use a factory to create these specialized decks for you rather than their constructors.

As an *example*, maybe refactor something like this:

Change your base `Deck` to just take the set of cards:

```
public abstract class Deck
{
    public List<Card> Cards;
    protected Deck(IEnumerable<Card> cards)
    {
        this.Cards = new List<Card>(cards);
    }
}
```

Then have the factory setup like this:

```
public class EuchreDeck : Deck
{
    private EuchreDeck(IEnumerable<Card> cards) : base(cards)
    {

    }

    public class Factory : DeckFactory
    { 
        private static readonly string[] Values = new string[] { "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
        private static readonly string[] Suits = new string[] { "clubs", "spades", "hearts", "diamonds" };

        public static EuchreDeck Create()
        {
            var cards = CreateCards(Values, Suits);
            return new EuchreDeck(cards);
        }
    }
}
```

Instantiation/usage as:

```
EuchreDeck.Factory.Create();
```

You could play around with the factory usage. I just nested it in the class so you couldn't create a `EuchreDeck` with an invalid set of cards. Your `DeckFactory` base would have your conversion method (which looks like you currently have in your `Deck` constructor)

Beyond that, I'm not sure if you have a specific need for a `EuchreDeck`; I'm assuming you have other methods associated with it? If not, you could probably ditch the class altogether and just let the factory create a `Deck` with the needed cards.

Comment: Great answer, you addressed my specific issue and provided some design-level suggestions as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to have somewhere that variable decalred :

```
public EuchreDeck() : base(values, suits) // Error.
{}
```

where are `values` and `suits` declared?

You have to define them `static`, like:

```
static readonly string[] values = new string[] { "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
static readonly string[] suits = new string[] 
              { "clubs", "spades", "hearts", "diamonds" };
```

The thing is that `base(..)` can only access values *visible* in ctor scope. So you can not pass *instance* variables, as instance is not accessible on that level, but you can pass *ctor parameters* and *static members* of calling class.

Comment: They are declared in the derived class.

Comment: @Zach:ok, but what is a problem with that?

Comment: The problem was I didn't declare them as `static`, as you and others suggested.  That fixed the compile error, I'm now exploring using the factory approach as Chris suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18719450/1463649).

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the values and suits should be declared static.

```
static string[] values = new string[] { "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
static string[] suits = new string[] { "clubs", "spades", "hearts", "diamonds" };
```

That way, they will be available at when instantiating the new class.